# Как воспроизвести видео при наведении курсора мыши

Tags: html, jquery, css3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать воспроизведение видеоролика при наведении курсора мыши как на этом сайте http://www.transitplus.ru/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.onmouseover = function(){
vid.play();
}
vid.onmouseup = function(){
vid.stop();
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo">
<source src="/yourSource/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```